# ¿Por qué Docker me devuelve el error "returned a non-zero code: 127"?

Tags: linux, docker, pip

Muy buenos días estoy intentando hacer mi primera imagen en docker usando el siguiente código:

```
#With the next line will be installd the operative system
FROM ubuntu

#Is the actualization of repository
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get update

#The next command help you to install git for can clone a repository from GitHub
RUN apt install git -y

#Installing Python and pip
RUN apt-get install python3.6 -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y

#install stringMLST
RUN pip install stringMLST
```

sin embargo cuando quiero continuar me sale el siguiente error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install stringMLST' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Ojalá me puedan ayudar

Comment: y si intentas que corra más bien `python -m pip install stringsMLST`

Comment: Realizaste lo que comenta @Alfabravo ???

Comment: muchísimas gracias si se ejecuto solamente que el comando fue : ```python3 -m pip install stringMLST``` @Alfabravo

Comment: Ahí te dejo entonces como respuesta para que la aceptes y los demás sepan qué hacer si tienen tu mismo problema :)

Comment: No existe el comando `pip` porque has instalado `python3-pip`. Creo que lo que debiste haber hecho era: `RUN pip3 install stringMLST`. Como puedes ver en el error, el comando `pip` no existe.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente hay algunos enredos al hacer que pip se ejecute como comando.

Para ir a la fija, siempre se puede usar

`python -m pip install stringsMLST`

O para especificar aún más que se quiere usar python3 (cuando pueda estar python2 por ahí)

`python3 -m pip install stringsMLST`